# While Loop to ask for user input and work out the average input values

Tags: python-3.x

I've been tasked to ask a user for an input using a while loop so that it recurs to ask the question until the condition is no longer True.

I understand how you construct a while loop and I have found the appropriate code to construct the code that is fit to my task.

I just wanted an insight of knowledge to the code `num.append(number)`
I understand that it removes that last inputted value, but I wanted to understand why the variable 'number' is stored within that bracket

```
num = []

while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if number == -1:
        break


    num.append(number) 

if not num:
        ("No number entered.")

else:
     avg = sum(num)/len(num)
     print(avg)
```

Comment: It might help to add the line `print(num)` after `num.append(number)` so you can see what that is doing.

Comment: *"I wanted to understand why the variable 'number' is stored within that bracket"* - Why wouldn't it be?  What happens when you change that?  What do you think that line of code does and why?

Comment: I see what that does now, but why would that variable be created then?
Is it so that it could be iterated?
When i first tackled this problem I kept coming to a type error where int is not iterable which I understand.
Is this to make it so that you're able to iterate it?

Comment: in order to calculate the average you need to know the sum and count of the inputs. You store those inputs in a list so you can do just that.

Comment: ahh ok, I understand now. 
I was just confused with the square brackets cause of how they are used in indexing
Thank you!